# How to iterate through an array of hashes inside an object with perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to iterate through an array of hashes stored as the '_skills' attribute of a 'Person' object, and having trouble.

test1.pl

```
my $person = new Person( "Hubert", "Blu",
    [
       {"name" => "Python", "Weight" => 80, "group","IT SKILLS", "id"=>0002},
       {"name" => "Magic", "Weight" => 100, "group", "MISC SKILLS", "id"=>0001},
       {"name" => "JavaScript","Weight" => 70, "group"=> "IT SKILLS", "id"=>0004},
       {"name" => "Mage","Weight" => 100, "group"=>"JOB TITLE", "id" =>0003},
       {"name" => "Assassin", "Weight" => 85, "group"=>"JOB TITLE"}
    ]
);
```

and Person.pl

```
sub new {
    my ($class,$first_name,$last_name,@skills) = @_ ;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{"_first_name"} = $first_name;
    $self->{"_last_name"} = $last_name;
    @{$self->{"_skills"}} = @skills;
    # Print all the values just for clarification.
    print "First Name is $self->{_first_name}\n";
    print "Last Name is $self->{_last_name}\n";
    print "Skills : " . Data::Dumper::Dumper($self->{_skills}) . "\n";


    print"---SKILLS---\n";
    my $i = 1;
    foreach my $skill_set (@{$self->{_skills}}) {
        print "skill ".$i .": \n";
        $i++;
        #print Data::Dumper::Dumper($skill_set) . "\n";
        print "$skill_set->{'_first_name'}";
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}
```

the first dump shows the array and it looks fine. the second dump inside the loop displays the entire array again, and it only loops through once before finishing with the following error

```
Not a HASH reference at /home/izoom/PerlTrainingGround/LeeR/lib/Person/Person.pm line 26.
```

Been stuck for hours any help appreciated as always!

Comment: Tip: Since `$self->{"_skills"}` is undef, `@{$self->{"_skills"}} = @skills;` is better written as `$self->{"_skills"} = \@skills;`

Comment: Tip: You should avoid indirect method call syntax. Replace `new Person (...)` with `Person->new(...)`.

Comment: The [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (Perl Data Structures Cookbook) docs have lots of examples :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing three arguments to `new` plus the invocant. The last is a reference to an array. That means that `@skills` ends up with a single element whose value is that reference.

```perl
my $person = new Person( "Hubert", "Blu",
    [
       {"name" => "Python", "Weight" => 80, "group","IT SKILLS", "id"=>0002},
       {"name" => "Magic", "Weight" => 100, "group", "MISC SKILLS", "id"=>0001},
       {"name" => "JavaScript","Weight" => 70, "group"=> "IT SKILLS", "id"=>0004},
       {"name" => "Mage","Weight" => 100, "group"=>"JOB TITLE", "id" =>0003},
       {"name" => "Assassin", "Weight" => 85, "group"=>"JOB TITLE"}
    ]
);
```

should be

```perl
my $person = new Person( "Hubert", "Blu",
   {"name" => "Python", "Weight" => 80, "group","IT SKILLS", "id"=>0002},
   {"name" => "Magic", "Weight" => 100, "group", "MISC SKILLS", "id"=>0001},
   {"name" => "JavaScript","Weight" => 70, "group"=> "IT SKILLS", "id"=>0004},
   {"name" => "Mage","Weight" => 100, "group"=>"JOB TITLE", "id" =>0003},
   {"name" => "Assassin", "Weight" => 85, "group"=>"JOB TITLE"}
);
```

or

```perl
    my ($class,$first_name,$last_name,@skills) = @_ ;

    @{$self->{"_skills"}} = @skills;     # Useless shallow array copy
       # -or-
    $self->{"_skills"} = [ @skills ];    # Same[1] but clearer
       # -or-
    $self->{"_skills"} = \@skills;       # No copy of elements
```

should be

```perl
    my ($class,$first_name,$last_name,$skills) = @_ ;

    @{$self->{"_skills"}} = @$skills;    # Shallow array copy
       # -or-
    $self->{"_skills"} = [ @$skills ];   # Same[1] but clearer
       # -or-
    $self->{"_skills"} = $skills;        # No copy of elements
```

---

1. Since `$self->{"_skills"}` is `undef` at this point.

Comment: In a sample loop pass, `$skill_set` is assigned the result of `{"name" => "Assassin", "Weight" => 85, "group"=>"JOB TITLE"}`...

Comment: my hero.  i had the wrong key in the hash which is why i had uninitialised variable its working perfect now! thanks again

Comment: just to elaborate i changed my code to your second option and it worked to iterate but i still had errors which turned out to be a simple wrong variable name, thanks again!